# how to setup Wiremock dynamic port

Tags: java, spring-boot, wiremock

I am working on integration test written in Spring boot 5 and I am trying to stub downstream services. I have several clients and 3 integration test classes.
In my resources folder I have .yml file with following configs:

```
downstream:
    service
        getSomeData:
            url: http://localhost:666
        getAuthToken:
            url: http://localhost:666
        someOtherClientMethod:
            url: http://localhost:666
```

And I am using Junit 5 with @WiremockTest annotation.

```
@WireMockTest(httpPort=666)
class TestSomething {
```

On my local machine clean build and test commands are working fine, but have fails in Jenkins with error:

> com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.FatalStartupException at WireMockServer.java.149
> Caused by: java.lang.RunTimeException at JettyServer.java:198
> Caused by: java.net.SocketException at Net.java:-2

As I understand the problem is that I have fixed port and I have to use dynamic port. Any suggestions how can I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lower port ranges are sometimes not allowed. Can you try higher port ranges ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).